# Tomcat not expanding ROOT.war but expand all other wars

Tags: java, tomcat6

I'm having a very strange issue, if the war file name is someothing other than ROOT.war then it gets expanded and the corresponding folder created. But if the war name is ROOT.war it doesn't expand.

What can be the issue ? Any idea/help ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

server.xml is something like below

```
<host..>
...
<context path=""...
</host>
```

I changed `path=""` to `path="/"` and this did the trick.

I'm answering my own question, so that it help others.